# CMake doesn't show version

Tags: python, cmake, ubuntu-18.04

```
$cmake --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pranto/.local/bin/cmake", line 7, in <module>
    from cmake import cmake
ImportError: cannot import name 'cmake'
```

Ubuntu 18.04,
Python = 3.6.

I recently upgraded my python version from 2.7 to 3.6, then starting seeing this error. How can I solve this?

Comment: You might try reinstalling CMake on your machine. How did you install CMake?

Comment: I have solved the problem already. Thanks for your reply

Comment: How did you solve it? Please consider writing an *answer* post to answer your own question, explaining how you resolved the issue. This way, others can learn from your post, and understand the solution.

Comment: Recently I moved from python=2.7 to python=3.6 and this is the reason I got the error. Solution:  $pip3 install cmake

Answer (score 0):

*To document the OP's solution:*

You have to **re-install** CMake within the new Python environment (3.6):

```
pip3 install cmake
```